# Groupby all items in a bag in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have a tuple with an element and a bag. The following is the example.

```
url1     {(tag1),(tag2),(tag3),(tag4)}
url2     {(tag1),(tag2),(tag3)}
url3     {(tag1),(tag2),(tag3)}
url4     {(tag1),(tag2),(tag3),(tag4)}
```

I would like to group all the elements by bag values.

```
{(tag1),(tag2),(tag3),(tag4)}     url1,url4
{(tag1),(tag2),(tag3)}            url2,url3
```

I am newbie to pig and any ideas or resources or pointers on how it can be done could be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the input data set for this use case ?

Comment: @Murali Rao we wrote a UDF to get the data in the following schema (url:chararray, date:chararray, mime:chararray,leafpaths {t:(xpath:chararray)}) 

and hence we got the above example output. Are we designing the schema correctly?